# Col-md=xx bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

minha duvida hoje é a seguinte:

Eu posso colocar um col-md maior dentro de um menor?

Por exemplo:

```
            <div class="col-md-6 ">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p> Texto aqui</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Minha lógica: 
A segunda div ocuparia 100% da primeira.
Só quero saber se estou certo.

Comment: correto, col-md-6 utiliza 50% do espaço enquanto col-md-12 é 100%. sua segunda div teria o tamanho da primeira.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, mas deve haver um outra linha entre eles:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
            <div class="col-md-9">.col-md-9</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```